# Jquery target non child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a series of tabs that open using the jquery .animate method. They all have the same class names so i am using the .children method to open only the clicked tab.

The problem is i need to close all the other tabs when one opens. I need to target all the tab-inner classes excluding the child of the one clicked.

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-inner">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-inner">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab">
    <div class="tab-inner">
    </div>
</div>

$('.tab').toggle(function() {
        $(this).children('.tab-inner').animate({width: 840});
  }, function() {
        $(this).children('.tab-inner').animate({width: 60});
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).siblings().children('.tab-inner')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just animate all of the`.tab-inner` elements first:

```
$('.tab').toggle(function() {
    $('.tab-inner').animate({ width : 60 });
    $(this).children('.tab-inner').animate({ width : 840 });
}, function() {
    $(this).children('.tab-inner').animate({ width : 60 });
});
```